# Passing ID via nested resource on create, value is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a route, which I've created a form_for

```
new_offer_lead GET    /offers/:offer_id/leads/new(.:format)      leads#new
```

The leads#new action works.

However, let's say I submit through /offers/1/leads/new   The offer_id is not being passed to my Lead model.

Lead.column_names

```
 Lead.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "email", "zip", "sport", "created_at", "updated_at", "offer_id"]
```

When I create a new lead, I can clearly see the new value in the Lead model, but the offer_id is nil.

Models

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :coupons
    belongs_to :offer

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :leads
```

Form for

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@lead,  layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>
          <%= f.text_field :name, :id => "myclass" %>
        </p>

        <p>

          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= f.text_field :sport %>
        </p>

          <p>
          <%= f.text_field :zip %>
        </p>


        <p id= "get-coupon-btn">
          <%= f.submit "Get Coupon!", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
         </p>
  </div>
```

Routes:

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
resources :offers do
    resources :leads
  end

  devise_for :users
  resources :offers
  resources :coupons
  resources :leads
```

My lead#create controller action

```
def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])

    if @lead.save

      Coupon.assign_coupon(@lead)
      redirect_to(@lead) #print the notice

    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Ignore the assign_coupon thing. Any ideas on how I can pass the offer_id into the lead model on create of the lead? Trying to get my head around nested resources and accepts resources for, but can't seem to analogize it to my current situation. Thank you!

Update 1: now this is erroring out: Couldn't find Offer with 'id'=

```
@offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
@lead = @offer.leads.build lead_params

if @lead.save
  .....
```

Calling the "build" funcion  on a relational attribute, it'll return an instance of that relational object (not persisted) with the id of the object that's referencing it. In this case it returns an instance of "Lead" with the value of  offer_id.

Comment: Please add some text to describe why this solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your form_tag as well:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@offer,@lead],  layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
```

This should give you and `offer_id` in your controller.